# Error with TabWidget in Android

Tags: android

I'm following the tutorial from androiddevelopers website. I copied the code and mTabHost is giving an error. I looked to see if anything needs to be imported, but everything is imported.

the code

```
package com.tabTestx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TabTestXActivity extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTabHost = getTabHost();

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}
```

Someone please help me

Comment: @Aerrow the mTabHost is underlined in red. I didn't run it yet.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working.


Just needed TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to declare `mTabHost` as `TabHost`

```
TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost(); //declare as TabHost in your code
^^^^^^^
```

Comment: How would I add another textview to the same tab_test1?

Comment: you can't.you can add more text in string `("tab_test1 here add another text ...")`, but cant add more than one text

Comment: you cant add anything instead of Text.

Comment: Yes, I already have one checkbox.. I need one more. not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have android:id/tabhost in xml?

```
      <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@android:color/white">


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Import TabHost, like this,

```
TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();
```

For More information refer these links, http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html and http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2011/03/tablayout-or-tabbed-view-android.html